# Is there any benefit to completing the "Advanced" Augmented Reality Training?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm still early in the game, but I stopped for a few minutes to finish up the Augmented Reality Training challenges.  Completing the first set of them earned me a new gadget.

However, a bunch more "Advanced" challenges unlocked, and I'm absolutely terrible at them.  I've considered just leaving them for now, and coming back when I have more experience, but I'm worried that perhaps something useful will unlock if I can finish them off now.

Is there any reason to finish up these challenges now, or can I safely move on with the game?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After getting the Grapnel Booster from the basic challenges, the only other reward you will receive is a trophy of the Batwing, which you can view through the menu.

There is, however, also an Xbox and Steam [achievement](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/batman-arkham-city/achievement/57302-AR-Knight.html) for completing all the Augmented Reality training missions.

> **AR Knight**
>
> Complete all augmented reality training exercises

Answer (score 5):

You don't get anything else in regards to gameplay for completing the Advanced Augmented Reality Training. For completing them all, you get the **AR Knight** achievement. Unfortunately, completing all of the ART sequences is a Sidequest, so in order to get the **Perfect Knight - Day 2** achievement, you'll have to complete them.